# setting the automatically enumerated text in the middle of the row

Tags: tables, enumerate

I've enumerated my text in rows but it's not in the middle of the row and I don't know how to achieve that.

[image: example]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,multirow,geometry}
\geometry{paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=25mm,top=30mm}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\let\oldtabularx\tabularx
\renewcommand{\tabularx}{\setcounter{rowcount}{-1}\oldtabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|@{\space\stepcounter{rowcount}\ifnum\value{rowcount}=0\else\therowcount.\thinspace\fi}X|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Typologie} & \textbf{Subgruppe} \\
\hline
\hline
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.
  \\
\hline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\
\hline

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

I've tried it with `\multirows` and `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` but that just created other problems of layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,multirow,geometry}
\geometry{paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=25mm,top=30mm}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\let\oldtabularx\tabularx
\renewcommand{\tabularx}{\setcounter{rowcount}{-1}\oldtabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\stepcounter{rowcount}\ifnum\value{rowcount}=0\else\therowcount.\thinspace\fi\hangindent=1em}X|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Typologie} & \textbf{Subgruppe} \\
\hline
\hline
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\
\hline
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\
\hline

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

If you need more than 9 rows let's define a new column type `N`:

```
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\stepcounter{rowcount}%
  \ifnum\value{rowcount}=0\else\therowcount.\thinspace\fi%
  \ifnum\value{rowcount}>9\hangindent=1.5em\else\hangindent=1em\fi}X}
```

so that the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,multirow,geometry}
\geometry{paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=25mm,top=30mm}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\let\oldtabularx\tabularx
\renewcommand{\tabularx}{\setcounter{rowcount}{-1}\oldtabularx}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{\stepcounter{rowcount}%
  \ifnum\value{rowcount}=0\else\therowcount.\thinspace\fi%
  \ifnum\value{rowcount}>9\hangindent=1.5em\else\hangindent=1em\fi}X}
\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|N|X|}
\hline
\textbf{Typologie} & \textbf{Subgruppe} \\
\hline
\hline
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\
\hline
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\
\hline
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\
\hline
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\
\hline
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\
\hline
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\
\hline
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\
\hline
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\
\hline
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\
\hline
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\
\hline
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\
\hline
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\
\hline
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\
\hline
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\
\hline

\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Nice solution for the alignment but it encounters some trouble if the numbers goes further than 9 since the `\hangindent=1em` is not big enough for 10 for instance. Do you have a workaround for that?

Comment: @LudovicC. added in the answer...

Answer (score 1):

I almost get what you are looking for... I am just missing an alignment for the text but hopefully someone will come with a fix for that!

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,geometry}
\geometry{paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=25mm,top=30mm}
\newcounter{rowcount}
\setcounter{rowcount}{0}
\let\oldtabular\tabular
\renewcommand{\tabular}{\setcounter{rowcount}{-1}\oldtabular}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|>{\stepcounter{rowcount}\raggedright\arraybackslash\ifnum\value{rowcount}=0\else\therowcount.~\fi}m{0.5\textwidth}|m{0.5\textwidth}}
\hline
\textbf{Typologie} & \textbf{Subgruppe} \\
\hline
\hline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet & consectetuer adipiscing elit. Etiam lobortis facilisis sem.
  \\
\hline
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. & Etiam lobortis facilisis sem. \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

My solution uses the `tabular` environment and the `>{<cmd>}` option instead of a `@{<cmd>}` option for the first column. This ensures that the counter will be at the same level as the first word of the cell. Then to vertically align it, I just use the `m` column descriptor.

Here is the output:

[image: Output]

**NOTE** There is still a problem with the horizontal alignment of the text in the cell if it needs to spread on more than one line. The text "restarts" under the number and not under the first word of the previous line as it seems to be desired on your picture.

**EDIT** I was just missing the `\hangindent` feature... See karlkoeller's answer to fix that.